# Astra theme is not reflecting the changes I am making

Tags: wordpress, layout, datastax-astra

I am testing Astra Pro and on trying to configure the page layout sidebar to the left, sidebar continues to the write.

Also, I tried moving the title upwards within the banner and on doing so, the title simply disappears.

Also, unable to change the width dimensions.

I have tried clearing cache and testing the site in incognito mode and with kproxy.com and the problem persists.

I am expecting to be able to view the changes reflected as I make them.

Comment: I am sure the problem is that what you did is not the right way to do it. You will have to think of another way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: But since nobody knows what you did and how you want to do this, nobody can help you at the moment.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want, what code you tried, what didn’t work, how you think what you did should work. I short, provide information instead of saying “it doesn’t work”.

Comment: Thank you all!!!Apparently the problem had something to do with VPI and cache problems.  That was the reason why I could not see the changes reflected in the browser. Thank you anyway!!

Comment: Hello again,   This is what happened.  With the help of my hosting supplier, we found out a tracerout problem . Because of this issue some changes were not being relfected.  Now my question is this:  Can I work on WordPress Customizer. Elementor and Spectra in the same website?

Comment: I am asking this because I downloaded a template which automatically activated Spectra, but I already had Elementor installed. I was trying to learn some Wordpress Customizer configurations and Ifound out that if I activated Elementor together with Spectra, the whole work was lost. Deactivating Elementor, the work was again recovered and displayed. I am asking this because now I don´t know if the issue starts because of these plugins incompatibility, or due to the tracerout issue.  Please advice. Thank you very much

Comment: In any case, I would like to learn if Spectra and Elementor can be integrated and work together on a given website. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this link will provide an answer: https://wpspectra.com/beaver-builder-vs-elementor-vs-spectra/#:~:text=Another%20notable%20feature%20of%20Spectra,inside%20the%20Elementor%20page%20builder.

Comment: To quote from it: “Another notable feature of Spectra is its compatibility with other popular plugins.

If you have Spectra and Elementor installed on your website, you can access Spectra’s prebuilt pages and blocks library inside the Elementor page builder.”

Comment: In any case: this is a different quetion altogether. So maybe you will have to post it as an entirely new question here…

Comment: Hi there again! and thank you for your feedback. The problem fortunately has been solved with the help of my hosting provider. One thing I would like to post is that Spectra and Elementor don´t work fine together since one overwrites the other one. I have tried it and all Spectra blocks were overriden with Elementor.